# Remove adjustable pipe clamp without head

Tags: plumbing

I'm attempting to replace a bathroom sink drain and figured this rubber flexible coupling would be a prime spot to disconnect the old. However the two clamps don't seem to have a slot for a screwdriver to undo/adjust.

Front:
[image]
Back (no the slight line is not an indentation for a screwdriver).
[image]

Is there a special trick to adjust/loosen these clamps or will I just have to cut it off?

Comment: Looks like you need to use a socket wrench or regular wrench; have you tried that?

Comment: @ UnhandledExcepSean    You should type that in as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a socket or regular wrench to turn those types of clamp screws.

Comment: wow I didn't see the hex shape